# how to test a setTimeout in these function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine

I have a function (in node.js ) that call another a setTimeout function. And i  need test with jasmine, if   setTimeout function was call , but i dont now how to do these

I expect test a call to the setTimeout function with jasmine

```
  const genOfGrid = (ctx, grid) => {
   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, fieldSize, fieldSize);
   drawGrid(ctx, grid);
   const gridOfNextGeneration = NextGeneration(grid);
   //These is the function i want to test
   setTimeout(() => {
     requestAnimationFrame(() => genOfGrid(ctx, gridOfNextGeneration));
    }, 1000 / 10);
 };

//These is the test implementation but It doesn't work

describe("Test settTimeout in genOfGrid", function() {
  let timerCallback;
  beforeEach(function() {
   timerCallback = jasmine.createSpy("timerCallback");
   jasmine.clock().install();
  });
  afterEach(function() {
   jasmine.clock().uninstall();
 });
fit("causes a timeout to be called synchronously", function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
   timerCallback();
   }, 100);
   expect(timerCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
 });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that will help you but if you want to test the generator `genOfGrid` you can try this:

```
// we need all those dependencies as injections so we can mock them
const genOfGridFactory = (drawGrid, NextGeneration, fieldSize, requestAnimationFrame) => (ctx, grid) => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, fieldSize, fieldSize);
  drawGrid(ctx, grid);
  const gridOfNextGeneration = NextGeneration(grid);
  //These is the function i want to test
  setTimeout(() => {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => genOfGrid(ctx, gridOfNextGeneration));
  }, 1000 / 10);
};
```

```
it('causes a timeout to be called synchronously', () => {
  const requestAnimationFrameMock = jasmine.createSpy('requestAnimationFrame').and.callFake((cb) => cb()); // instant execution
  const genOfGrid = genOfGridFactory(
    drawGridStub,
    NextGenerationMock,
    fieldSizeStub,
    requestAnimationFrameMock
  )// setup them as you wish
  const spy = spyOn(genOfGrid);
  const ctxStub = ...;
  genOfGrid(ctxStub, gridStub, NextGenerationMock);
  jasmine.clock().tick(1000/10);// progress enough time to trigger setTimeout requestAnimationFrameMock will trigger its interior immediately
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(ctxStub, NextGenerationMock(gridStub));
});
```